# Custom wordpress SQL statement for a website

Tags: database, mysql, select, join-tables

I'm trying to link specific columns from a few standard tables in a wordpress database. I specifically want to see a view/table that includes:

```
post title
post content
guid
meta value = image url
```

This kind of works but I have 3 rows per item returned. I just want one, then to be able to select the newest item from all categories except 2, 4 and 7 for example.

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.`guid`, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'image_url'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

I've been on this task for 3 days and searched hi and lo, watched videos, followed tuts and am about to pull my hair out.

Answer (score -1):

I think this could be life saver for you .
This is a simple function for creating multiple loops. It retrieves a list of **latest posts** or posts matching criteria.

```
<?php $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>




<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts'     => 5,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'category'        => ,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'include'         => ,
    'exclude'         => ,
    'meta_key'        => ,
    'meta_value'      => ,
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'  => ,
    'post_parent'     => ,
    'post_status'     => 'publish' ); ?>
```

for exclude categories try adding a minus sign in front of category id.

Comment: hey thanks there, but thats the php side of it (which i hate) and dreamweaver took care of that for me. i was hoping to cover it in sql ?)